# How to install pantheon desktop on ubuntu

Tags: pantheon

I want to install pantheon desktop on ubuntu server 20.04. I've looked at a few guides online and they all tend to suggest the below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

After going through these steps and i reboot ubuntu, I now have a GUI which I didn't have before. However when I login and I select my desktop environment I just have the two options of "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Wayland". Why is Pantheon not showing here?